# Undefined reference to `msm_nand_data' while compiling hammerhead kernel with ubifs support?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-kernel

I am trying to compile a Nexus 5 kernel(hammerhead) with ubifs support. I have used the android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1 build. I have followed the following steps :

1. make hammerhead_defconfig
2. make menuconfig
   And Enabled..

   ```
   Device Drivers --->
        Memory Technology Device (MTD) support  --->
            Enable UBI - Unsorted block images  --->

   File systems  --->
        Miscellaneous filesystems  ---> 
             UBIFS file system support
   ```

But I am getting the following compilation error :

```
CC      init/version.o
LD      init/built-in.o
LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
drivers/built-in.o: In function `flash_onfi_probe':
/home/usr/android/msm/drivers/mtd/devices/msm_nand.c:765: undefined reference to 'msm_nand_data'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

What might be causing this error ?

**EDIT** : I could solve this issue by disabling **Self Contained Device Drivers --> MTD_MSM_NAND**

Comment: I am not sure what is causing the problem, but this might help you in debugging and fix the issue. do a ctags inside kernel directory "ctags -R ." then go the file +765 and press ctrl+], that will lead to that function definition, check whether the file where it is defined is getting compiled. if not check what is the CONFIG used to  compile that file.

Comment: @AvK msm_nand_data is a struct defined in the platform data.  Did you include that in your build?  Is CONFIG_MACH_HALIBUT defined?

Comment: @kzs Can you explain the debugging process bit elaboratly, I want to learn this method of debugging by the use of ctags. I didnt get your statement "then go the file +765" properly.